# How to make a mysql query which returns only the elements which have the same first word with the content of an array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, regex

I have an array with first names and a column on a mysql table with completed names (first name and last name). How can I write a mysql query which compares the elements of the array and the elements of the column and returns the completed names only if the first name is in the array too. I don't want to use the explode function. Thanks in advance!

```
   id      |      completed_names

-----------------------------------
    1       |   John Mclay
    2       |   John Ross
    3       |   Will John
    4       |   Brian Cosby
    5       |   Brian Dave

$names_array=array("John" ,"Brian");

sql_query="SELECT completed_names FROM myTable WHERE completed_names=".$names_array[].";
```

As a result  I would like to have all the elements except the 3rd.

Comment: Anything if you tried, please show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LIKE syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html)

...`WHERE completed_names LIKE 'john%' OR completed_names LIKE 'brian%'`

Or [REGEXP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/regexp.html) if more accuracy is needed.

...`WHERE completed_names REGEXP '^(john|brian)[[:>:]]'`

`[[:>:]]` matches a word boundary. `^` matches start. For this you can just **implode** your array.

```
$sql_query = "SELECT completed_names FROM myTable
              WHERE completed_names REGEXP '^(".implode("|", $names_array).")[[:>:]]'";
```